# Pointers & loops in C

Tags: c, loops, pointers

I have a problem with understanding the use of pointers in my C-program. The program is designed to print out all elements in the array. The most confusing part is the for-loop that doesnt seem to make sense for me. What is the value of p from the beginning? How does the loop stop if the condition p < a + n always is true?

```
    void element(int a[], int n)
   {
     for (int *p = a; p < a + n; p++)
        printf("%d   ", *p);

    }

       int main()
       {
        int f[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        element(f, 5);
        }
```

Comment: p < a + n is not always true since you are incrementing p.

Comment: "What is the value of p from the beginning?" -> Let's print: `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);`

Comment: "*What is the value of p from the beginning?*" -- the first clause in the `for` loop's control block sets the initial value of `p`: `int *p = a`.  That is, `p` is initialized with a copy of the value of `a`.

Comment: `p` is pointing to `a[0]` for the first iteration, pointing to `a[1]` for the second iteration, pointing to `a[n-1]` for the final iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code, p points to `a[0]`, then to `a[1]`, then `a[2]` and so on.

The condition `p < a + n` is terminating because when you increment p, it makes the pointer p move from `a[0]` to `a[1]` and so on, thus increasing its value and `a+n` is `1+5=6`.

So when p reaches 5, condition becomes false in next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

- `p` is a pointer to an integer (the asterisk in the declaration is what makes it a pointer)
- `p` Starts off pointing to the initial element of array `a`, which in this context is also a pointer
- Each iteration advances `p` by one integer position in memory
- The loop ends once `p` crosses over past the end of the array.

To learn more about the `a + n` expression read about pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a for loop is `for(/* do first */; /* continue doing while this is true */ ; /* do after the loop body */ )`.

Lets apply that to your `for (int *p = a; p < a + n; p++)`.

```
/* do first                    */ int *p = a /* introduce a pointer-to-int, initialised to a */
/* continue while this is true */ p < a + n  /* p is less than p+n, still within the array   */
/* do after the loop body      */ p++        /* increment the pointer by one "pointed-to" */
```

Note that `a` decays into a pointer to an `int` containing the address of the array, or the address of element at index 0 within that array and that `p+n` is the address AFTER the last element in the array, which is allowed to be compared to, but not accessed.